# fp equal to sp at startup but when copied onto enlarged stack changes to zero - why?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm

I'm learning x32 ARM assembly on RaspberryPi with Raspbian.  I wrote
the following code:

```
@ Define my Raspberry Pi
    .cpu    cortex-a53
    .fpu    neon-fp-armv8
    .syntax unified         @ modern syntax

.text
    .align  2
    .global main
    .type   main, %function

main:
    mov     r0, 1           @ line added only for breakpoint purposes
    sub     sp, sp, 8       @ space for fp, lr
    str     fp, [sp, 0]     @ save fp
    str     lr, [sp, 4]     @   and lr
    add     fp, sp, 4       @ set our frame pointer
```

Build with gcc:

```
gcc -g test.s -o test
```

Use `gdb` to check values of `fp` and `sp` in lines 13 and 16 and
dereference them:

```
$ gdb ./test
(gdb) break 13
Breakpoint 3 at 0x103d4: file test.s, line 13.
(gdb) break 16
Breakpoint 4 at 0x103e0: file test.s, line 16.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/assembly/nine/bob/test

Breakpoint 3, main () at test.s:13
13              sub     sp, sp, 8       @ space for fp, lr
(gdb) print {$sp, $fp}
$1 = {0x7efffae8, 0x7efffae8}
(gdb) x $sp
0x7efffae8:     0x76f9e000
(gdb) x $fp
0x7efffae8:     0x76f9e000
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 4, main () at test.s:16
16              add     fp, sp, 4       @ set our frame pointer
(gdb) print {$sp, $fp}
$2 = {0x7efffae0, 0x7efffae0}
(gdb) x $sp
0x7efffae0:     0x00000000
(gdb) x $fp
0x7efffae0:     0x00000000
```

As you see `fp` is equal to `sp` at startup and non-zero:

```
(gdb) print {$sp, $fp}
$1 = {0x7efffae8, 0x7efffae8}
(gdb) x $sp
0x7efffae8:     0x76f9e000
(gdb) x $fp
0x7efffae8:     0x76f9e000
```

but when copied onto the enlarged stack it changes to zero

```
(gdb) x $fp
0x7efffae0:     0x00000000
```

Why does it change to zero?  Why does it change value at all?  Is
underlying implementation somehow linking values of `fp` and `sp` so
that when `sp` is moved down to the initialized memory that might be
all zeroes `fp` is changed as well? I only found
[this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/Cihcjeij.html):

> ```
> fp
>
> Is the frame pointer register. In the obsolete APCS variants that
> use fp, this register contains either zero, or a pointer to the
> most recently created stack backtrace data structure. As with the
> stack pointer, the frame pointer must be preserved, but in
> handwritten code it does not need to be available at every
> instant. However, it must be valid whenever any strictly
> conforming function is called. fp must always be preserved.
> ```

[This
comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316915/fp-equal-to-sp-at-startup-but-when-copied-onto-enlarged-stack-changes-to-zero?noredirect=1#comment108477450_61316915)
says that `lr` is stored as the first element on the stack but it's
definitely not - it stays the same and is not zero:

```
(gdb) print {$sp, $fp, $lr}
$1 = {0x7efffae8, 0x7efffae8, 0x76e6b718 <__libc_start_main+268>}
```

and after `sp` changes:

```
(gdb) x/2xw $sp
0x7efffae0:     0x00000000      0x76e6b718
```

Comment: Doesn't `x $fp` print the memory contents pointed to by `fp`? The value of `fp` appears to be `0x7efffae0` at that point.

Comment: Yes, it does - that's why I mentioned `dereference them`. But I don't
understand why does it point to 0.

Comment: Well, the value you've stored there appears to be `lr`. I don't know enough about raspberry pi development to say if it makes sense for `lr` to be 0.

Comment: @Michael: it's not `lr` - it's not zero and it's correctly saved just after what is supposed to store `fp` - see edit.

Comment: @Michael: I'm not sure this is RaspberryPi-specific - it can be how GNU as, glibc, Linux and ARM CPU work together

Comment: @Michael: well, my current, not so educated guess is that `$fp` is not used on ARM in the newest AAPCS and that this is just how `gdb` shows contents of `fp`. Also, `fp` is not even shown by `info registers`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm answering myself - this happens in `gdb/arm-tdep.c` in GDB source code:

```
  /* The frame size is just the distance from the frame register
 to the original stack pointer.  */
  if (pv_is_register (regs[ARM_FP_REGNUM], ARM_SP_REGNUM))
{
  /* Frame pointer is fp.  */
  framereg = ARM_FP_REGNUM;
  framesize = -regs[ARM_FP_REGNUM].k;
}
  else
{
  /* Try the stack pointer... this is a bit desperate.  */
  framereg = ARM_SP_REGNUM;
  framesize = -regs[ARM_SP_REGNUM].k;
}
```